# Why are query params processed into @FormParam arguments in @POST?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cxf

I annotate my [`@POST`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/POST.html) method arguments as [`@FormParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) in hopes that it will require they be submitted only in an HTTP form and not as query string params:

```
@POST
@Path("domain/registerEntity")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response registerEntity(@FormParam("param1") String param1,
        @FormParam("param2") String param2) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    ...
}
```

However, I am able to post a URL ***/domain/registerEntity?param1=X&param2=Y** and the method still reads the query params into the variables *param1* and *param2* even though no form is being sent. My `jax-rs` implementation is `Apache CXF`.

How can I make sure that my POST ignores all the query parameters and only expect that they come in as form parameters?

I tested this in both `Chrome Poster` and `HttpClient` and it responds the same way in both clients.

Comment: Can you check the `content-type` header and restrict based on the type?

Comment: it is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: why would anyone downvote this ?

Comment: I don't think you can, and why do you care whether the value is in the content or in the query string?

Comment: because i want to disable sending data through the query string, for security purposes

Comment: Why? Are you logging the query strings? If it is for security, then it sounds like a general policy, so add a filter that rejects or sanitizes POST requests with query parameters.

Comment: i just want to treat the query params as though there were not there and accept params only if they come in as form

Comment: What does that have to do with security? So I ask again: Why do you care? --- But if you insist that you want to ignore query parameters on POST requests, create a filter to remove them from the request (aka sanitizing the request), like I already suggested.

Comment: because, it is not a good idea to put sensitive data in a URL:  http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/

Comment: the 2nd part of your most recent comment sounds like a solution -- can you post an answer with a code sample ?

Comment: Which implementation of ws.rs are you using? I am unable to replicate this with Jersey - it ignores query parameters in this instance.

Comment: @AndrewRueckert -- sorry, should have included that info in the OP.  I use `Apache CXF`